# Flask can't find folder to save an image to

Tags: python, flask

I have a favicon.ico that I want to save, but it won't let me. It says file/directory not found. Please help :)

I get an error at the self.file.save line.

[image]

This is my code:

```
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = '/static/files/settings/'
```

```
from app import app
class SettingsForm:
    def __init__(self, title, description, file):
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.file = file

        self.errors = []

    def save_img(self):
        if self.file:
            if self.allowed_file():
                try:
                    os.remove('static/files/settings/favicon.ico')
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    pass
                self.file.filename = 'favicon.ico'
                 self.file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], self.file.filename))
            else:
                self.errors.append('Rossz kiterjesztés.')

    def allowed_file(self):
        return '.' in self.file.filename and self.file.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in EXTENSIONS

    def change_settings(self):
        self.save_img()
        if self.title == '' or self.description == '':
            self.errors.append('Űrlap hiányos.')
        if len(self.errors) != 0:
            return self.errors
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = "UPDATE settings SET title = %s, description = %s;"
            cursor.execute(sql, (self.title, self.description))
            connection.commit()
            return 'Módosítás sikeres.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting a path with `/` makes it absolute. Do you really have a `/static` directory (a directory called `static` in the root of your drive, beside `/usr` and `/tmp`), and is that where files should go?

I suspect you mean the `static` directory in your project directory. Try removing the leading slash:

```
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'static/files/settings/'
```

Comment: No, it didn't work i tried it that way before

Comment: @Daniel To specify an absolute path you can use `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'files/settings')`

Comment: Okay, well `/static` is almost certainly wrong. Try Detlef's suggestion.